# Getting GetDecimal to work

Tags: c#, mysql, if-statement, decimal, datareader

```
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("host=*;user=*;password=*;database=*;");
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = '" + textBox2.Text + "' AND password = '" + textBox3.Text + "';");
cmd.Connection = con;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
con.Open();
MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (reader.Read() != false)
{
    if (reader.IsDBNull(0) == true)
    {
        cmd.Connection.Close();
        reader.Dispose();
        cmd.Dispose();
        MessageBox.Show("Oops!There was a problem!");
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Connection.Close();
        reader.Dispose();
        cmd.Dispose();
        this.Hide();
        Main main = new Main();
        main.Show();
        MySqlCommand cmmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT Pain FROM members WHERE username='" + textBox2.Text + "';");
        cmmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        MySqlDataReader read = cmmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (read.Read())
        {
            if (read.GetDecimal(0) == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("NO");
                cmmd.Connection.Close();
                read.Dispose();
                cmmd.Dispose();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("YES");
                cmmd.Connection.Close();
                read.Dispose();
                cmmd.Dispose();
            }
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("You Login Information is incorrect!");
}
```

I want the C# to read the PAIN column and if it's equal to 0 to show the message NO and if it's equal to 1 to show the message YES.The pain Collumn is an INT type and is the 8th column

Comment: _The pain Collumn is an INT type_  - then maybe use `GetInt32()` ?

Comment: Also, is this throwing an error ?

Comment: no, it's good now, THANK YOU SO MUCH :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as below.

```
using (var con = new MySqlConnection("host=*;user=*;password=*;database=*;"))
using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT username, Pain FROM members WHERE username = @UserName AND password = @Password";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", textBox2.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", textBox3.Text);

    con.Open();
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            var username = reader.GetString(0);

            if (!reader.IsDBNull(1))
            {
                var pain = reader.GetInt32(1);
                if (pain == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("NO");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("YES");
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You Login Information is incorrect!");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I got the following errors:              
The best overloaded method match for 'int.TryParse(string, out int)' has some invalid arguments      

Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'

Constant value '1' cannot be converted to a 'bool'

Comment: @VlasiuRobert is your pain column allow null values?

Comment: int? pain = (int?)cmmd.ExecuteScalar();Specified cast is not valid..You mean if the column is Null?

Comment: @VlasiuRobert I have added sample code with few of best practices, don't use inline parameters, you don't need manually dispose/close connection etc if you using `using blocks`, and also no need of two time call database for this